# Should I use a GridView or TableLayout for a Checkers/Draughts Board on Android?

Tags: android, xml, gridview, tablelayout

I'm pretty new to android, and I want to make a checkers game. Should I use a gridview, tablelayout, or something else to construct an 8x8 board on which you can place and move pieces. Please explain your answer: what are the specific benefits to whatever you think is best to create this board.

Thanks,
Evan

PS Any other suggestions for this app are also appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Between the `GridView` and the `TableLayout`, I'd go with the `GridView`.

You will see the benefits when you try to get the users' move. 
In a `TableLayout` you would have to write a switch{} for each of the 64 squares. 
In a `GridView` you can set an `onItemClickListener` to get the users' move, regardless of the position.

Comment: Okay. One more thing: how do you think I should display both the board and the pieces? Should I make two gridviews on top of each other, one that has the board and one that has the pieces?

Comment: And also, do you think i should use imagebuttons?

Comment: A canvas for the board would suffice.
A transparent gridview of 8x8 over it with imagebuttons for the pieces
and with the empty cells set to clickable=false,  is what you need

Comment: After you get a satisfying answer that addresses your questions, it is normal to award that answer as the "correct answer" by clicking the green tick, near that answer.